# Given a org.w3c.dom.Element, how do I find an Element within that given an xpath string?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm using Java 6.  As the question states, how would I write a method that takes an org.w3c.dom.Element and an xpath string and returns a list of matching org.w3c.dom.Elements, assuming there are any?

If it helps all the Elements were obtained by parsing XHTML documents.

**Edit:** Per the suggestion given, I tried

```
    final XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    final XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
    final NodeList result = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(xpathStr, rootElement, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

where my xpathStr was "//div[contains(@class,'listing')]/h3//a[1]/span/text()", however, the result is returning xpaths matching the entire parent document, and not just things in the "rootElement" Element object.  I have verified that the rootElement object doesn't contain some of the results returned within its HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good article on the topic: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/

Use [XPathFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathFactory.html) to create an XPath, and then use [xpath.evaluate("expression", contextNode, NODESET)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#evaluate%28java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.InputSource%29) to get the list of matching elements.

The contextNode is the "given element", and so any XPath expression evaluated from that starting point will give elements that are descendants of ("within") that element, depending on what axes they use.

Comment: I edited my question, but the method you suggest isn't working.  It is returning results matching the entire document, as opposed to only things within the Element I want to search.  Let me know what other information I should provide.

Comment: @Dave, it's not the method that's not working, but the XPath expression (hence the phrase "depending on what axes they use", in which "they" meant the "the XPath expression" - sloppy grammar). If your XPath starts with "//", you are selecting elements starting from the root of the document, regardless of the contextNode. If you insert `.` before the `//` at the front of your XPath, you will be selecting from the descendants of the context node (`rootElement`). (Again, assuming your XPath expression doesn't use unusual axes to break out of that subtree.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  The xpath expression indeed was the problem.